# Get highest role of a member with mentions

Tags: node.js, discord.js

How can I get the highest role name of a mentioned member? I tried something like this but it doesn't work. Thanks! :) btw this is a ban command and I need this bc my bot is crashing when someone is trying to ban a user with a higher rank than bot.

```
if(message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')){
    const user = message.mentions.users.first()
    console.log(user.roles.highest.name)
    if(!user) return console.log("test1")
    if(!args[2]) return console.log("test2")
    const ddays = args[1]
```

Comment: Can you share more code? For example a sample of your `user` and `message` objects?

Comment: I edited it... ik it doesn't help but I just need a code to check highest rank of user

Comment: Both objects mentioned in your comment are introduced by Discord.JS, a wrapper for the Discord API

Comment: i mean when i try `-ban @player` , the bot will check if `@player` has a higher role than the bot

Comment: @PascalStockert wdym ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention @10110 there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is:

Getting a user's highest role:

1. Get the [UserId](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members) from the [Mention](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Message?scrollTo=mentions) inside of the [Message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Message)
2. Get the [Cache](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=cache) from the [RoleManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Guild?scrollTo=roles) of the [Guild](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Message?scrollTo=guild) in which the Message was sent in
3. (I don't know if the roles in RoleCache are sorted by position, so sort if needed)
4. Iterate through the roles in RoleCache and [check if the UserId is contained inside](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Role?scrollTo=members) a specific role
5. Get the [position of the role](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Role?scrollTo=position)

Getting the bot's highest role:

1. Repeat steps 2-5 for your bot (or integrate them within the previous iteration of the RoleCache)

Then compare both numbers and find out if the bot's "role number" is higher than the one of the user's.